# uploading one file and having it save several times with different names

Tags: php, file, loops, upload, rename

I have to integrate with a relatively goofy system currently in place. Hence the goofy code. What I need is to have the user choose a pdf to upload. The pdf is then saved as cusip_HLD.pdf for as many cusips as there is.
For example

```
$fundID = 8
SELECT cusip FROM shareClass WHERE fundID = '$fundID'
```

Will return

```
|  CUSIP  |
| 1234567 |
| 7894561 |
| 3546841 |
```

The code that is currently in place is the following, but while it echos it saved several times, the `move_uploaded_file` appears to pull the file out of temp storage.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCusipsResult)){
        $cusip = $row['cusip'];
        $fullFileName = $cusip."_HLD.pdf";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "pdf/".$fullFileName);
        echo "Stored in: pdf/".$fullFileName;
    }
```

EDIT: How can I fix the code so the need stated above is fulfilled?

Comment: Your question is missing a question mark.

Comment: I stated a need, and I stated the need wasn't being fulfilled. I figured the question could be inferred

Comment: What "need" are you talking about? The only need you mention is "to have the user choose a pdf to upload." Not trying to be snarky, I really don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only **MOVE** the uploaded file once. After that it's no longer in the temp upload dir (because you moved it). If you need to create multiple copies of the file, then use a `copy` command instead, e.g.

```
while($row = ...) {
  $fullFileName = ...;
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
      copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "pdf/$fullFileName");
  }
}
```

if these files are not going to be modified by the users, then consider using a hardlink instead, so only one copy of the file is saved, and simply point the other "copies" at the original.

Comment: They aren't being modified by the users exactly. They are however being picked up by another process and based on their name different actions are taken upon them. But copy I would imagine would fix this problem perfectly. Thanks!